# Can't open .rtf attachment in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, crash, rtf

About couple weeks ago, I started having problems opening/saving .rtf attachments
in Outlook 2010. I have no problem with any other attachments, just .rtf
files. I've tried the Detect and Repair option, but am still unable to open
or save the .rtf file attachments. The error given tells me to check my
permissions.

Comment: If you save it to your computer first (say, on your desktop), can you then open it from there?  Which program is currently set to open RTF files on your system?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try **OpenOffice.ORG's Writer program**. In the wiki it said that it's recovered corrupted Word documents that MS Word couldn't recover. It's a long shot, and I doubt it'll work, but it's free to try.

If the methods above still don't work, I think you can try some professional tools. You ma try a utility called *RTF Repair Kit* to repair your Word document. It works rather well for my corrupt Word documents.

http://www.rtf.repair/

Hope this helps.